# How rewrite this code for Java 7

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx, javafx-8

I want to write this code for Java 7.

```
timeline.setOnFinished(actionEvent -> Platform.runLater(() -> {
        POPUP.hide();
        popups.remove(POPUP);
    }));
```

I wrote this:

```
timeline.setOnFinished(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
            POPUP.hide();
            popups.remove(POPUP);
        }
    });
```

But I'm not sure where to insert the rest of the code.

Where I have to insert `Platform.runLater(()`?

Comment: I think you mean Java 8? There is no lambda support in Java 7.

Comment: This code uses lambda expression. I want to back port the code for Java 7.

Comment: And what's wrong with how you wrote it?

Comment: I want to use it in Java 7. Where I have to inset `Platform.runLater(()`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
    timeline.setOnFinished(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
        public void handle(final ActionEvent e){
            Platform.runLater(
                    new Runnable(){
                        public void run(){
                            POPUP.hide();
                            popups.remove(POPUP);
                        }
                    }
            );
        }
    });
```